# Adding generic multiple textField in listview in wicket

Tags: listview, wicket, textfield

I need a to populate textFields dynamically in the web page and I have used listview for this

```
Form <BenificiaryFormModel> registerForm = new Form<BenificiaryFormModel>("registerForm",Model.of(new BenificiaryFormModel()));

    ListView listView = new ListView("registerListView", benificiaryRegFieldsList) {

                    @Override
                   protected void populateItem(ListItem item) {

                    LOG.debug("Increamenter value {}",incrementer);


                    BenificiaryRegFieldsBean listViewBean = (BenificiaryRegFieldsBean )item.getModelObject();

                     item.add(new Label("beneficiaryLabel", listViewBean .getLabel())); 


                        item.add(new TextField("beneficiaryTextField", new PropertyModel(benificiaryFormModel,"textFieldData."+incrementer)));//,"textFieldData."+incrementer)));
                     incrementer++;
                    }
            };
```

I refered the link [Retrieve values of dynamically added inputs of a form in Wicket](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23676435/retrieve-values-of-dynamically-added-inputs-of-a-form-in-wicket) and did the same but i am getting warning message and control doesn't come to onSumit Warn message as below: 
2015-07-16 12:17:50,484 [http-bio-8082-exec-9] WARN  org.apache.wicket.markup.html.form.AbstractTextComponent:166  - Couldn't resolve model type of Model:classname=[org.apache.wicket.model.PropertyModel]:nestedModel=[com.sybase365.mobiliser.web.beans.BenificiaryFormModel@bde32]:expression=[textFieldData.0] for [MarkupContainer [Component id = beneficiaryTextField]], please set the type yourself.

There will be mulitiple text box and label and only one submit button to update all the fields so please help me how to get values of the textfields onSumit

Answer (score 0):

Try using `item.setModel(new CompoundPropertyModel<YourBean>(item.getModelObject()));`

If you are using PropertyModel, then you need to define setter/getter in your page class. In case of CompoundPropertyModel, your bean's setter/getter would do that job.

Comment: @John Carpenter ,On submit how could i get the value of the component for example i need the value entered in the textField how could i get those value without  getter method and also there is only one submit button for multiple textfields i need to update all the value on one button onSubmit().

Comment: i did same as in link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23676435/retrieve-values-of-dynamically-added-inputs-of-a-form-in-wicket, but the contol does not come to button onSubmit itself , showing an warning message as below: WARN  org.apache.wicket.markup.html.form.AbstractTextComponent:166  - Couldn't resolve model type of Model:classname=[org.apache.wicket.model.PropertyModel]:nestedModel=[com.sybase365.mobiliser.web.beans.BenificiaryFormModel@bde32]:expression=[textFieldData.0] for [MarkupContainer [Component id = beneficiaryTextField]], please set the type yourself.

Comment: You would need to use bean.someRecordList as compound property model to have those values set into the list. Once you have the list, save it to database from service layer or whatever way you want to.

Comment: Small correction to clear possible confusion: you would need bean.someStringList as property name for the textfield list item component. Set/Get of that 'someStringList' will store the values for those textfields.